# Wrapping c++ struct template using cython

Tags: c++, templates, cython

I am attempting to access the struct

```
template <int dim>
struct Data { 
  double X[dim];
  double Val[dim];
};
```

in cython. I was guessing the correct syntax should be something like:

```
cdef extern from "Lib.h" namespace "LIB":
    cdef struct Data[int dim]:
      double X[dim];
      double Val[dim];
```

However, I am getting an syntax error. What is the correct syntax (if it is even possible)?

Comment: Answered here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cython-users/KoWokHegRWY/xsFSdOFZWeQJ

Answer (score 3):

Replace struct keyword to cppclass keyword. This should help.

```
  cdef extern from "Lib.h" namespace "LIB":
      cdef cppclass Data[int dim]:
        double X[dim];
        double Val[dim];
```

Also check out this thread: [C++ Struct inheritance in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781572/c-struct-inheritance-in-cython)