# Inheritance of struct in Cython

Tags: struct, cython

Is it possible to define a struct in Cython and then define another struct that inherits from that struct?

For example, if you did it in C++, then it would look like: [C++ Struct inheritance in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9781572/3654588) However, you cannot do the same related syntax in Cython:

```
cdef struct Base:
    # base members


# this doesn't work
cdef struct Derived : Base :
    # derived members
```

If not, why is it not possible and what are some ways around that?

Comment: It's not possible because C doesn't have inheritance. Cython here is just wrapping C language features rather than inventing new ones.

Comment: Do you know then what is a good way to create a struct-like container in Cython that can also do inheritance?

Would a c++ class do it? Would there be any performance loss though?

Comment: You can do it through composition of structs ("base struct as the first element of derived struct" is a pretty widely used ideom in C) or through C++ classes. I don't see why C++ classes would cause any performance loss (but equally it isn't obvious what you're doing with it that needs performance)